# CSV file storage vs Postgres database for multiple users

Tags: postgresql, github, plotly-dash

I have an dash app that features live-updates on CSV data uploaded to a private repository on Github at 5 minutes intervals. Currently the DASH app reads the entire CSV file at each update and populates the graphs. The app is hosted on heroku. I'm concerned about scalability of the app, as multiple users using the app will send API requests for CSV data of perhaps 30-70 rows of data potentially requiring a lot of dynos. Would hosting the data on Postgres prove advantages in any way? Currently, each new user has a separate folder in the github repository which makes API requests simple. Thank you. Note: I'm new to SQL, please be gentle.

Comment: The major problem on Heroku will be how your dynos all access the same CSV file. It needs to be somewhere shared, else every dyno will have to download and parse the CSV separately [and do it again every time they're restarted](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). A SQL database provides a central location for dynos to access data. It also provides a place to store user info, a folder per user on Github is not sustainable, and anything else. A single worker dyno would periodically fetch the CSV and load it into the database.

Comment: Thanks for the info. To clarify, each user has a unique CSV file on github, so I suppose that requires a separate dyno for each user? Sounds expensive. So setting up multiple unique databases corresponding to each user, on a single account is feesible on Postgres?

Comment: No need for multiple databases, a single record in a single database can have billions of records. For many many users. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: @RobertMarciniak Just one database, and probably three tables: one for your users, one for the data rows, and one to say which rows belong to which user; a many-to-many relationship. Basic SQL is out of scope for StackOverflow, and there are [coding frameworks which will make this easier](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/).